# How to generate specific random numbers in Python?

Tags: python, random

I need help with generating a list of specific random numbers using Python.

I know how to generate a list of random number like this

```
import random
number = random.sample(xrange(1,10), 3)
```

which will generate 3 random numbers between 1 to 10.
(Example)

```
[7, 6, 1]
```

What I want to do achieve is generating a list of random numbers like this with duplicate value(Example)

```
[10000, 30000, 20000, 60000, 100, 3000, 3000, 100, ...]
```

But using above script like this

```
import random
number = random.sample(xrange(10000,100000), 4)
```

yields following result (Example)

```
[12489, 43177, 51867, 68831]
```

Is it possible to do what I want to achieve here? Thank your answer.

Comment: So you want to round to the nearest 100?  Or only keep 1 significant figure?

Comment: It is unclear what you want... a single digit followed by between 2 and 4 0s?

Comment: @mgilson @Julien For example, if I put range between 100 until 1000, it will generate random number of  `[100, 200, 300, 100, 1000, 800,...]`. It does not have to be 2 or 4 0s, it can be one 0 or five 0s and more based on the range.

Comment: If you are generating random numbers you cannot expect to get duplicates - you may and you may not depending on the range and quantity of random numbers.

Comment: @wwii thank you for that advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for random numbers rounded to the thousands?

```
import random
numbers = [1000*x for x in random.sample(xrange(1,100), 4)]
```

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion is simpler and easy to understand. And yes, I am looking for random numbers rounded to the thousands.

Answer (score 2):

Something that looks like your example

```
import random
n1 = random.sample(xrange(1,10), 4)
n2 = random.sample(xrange(2,6), 4)
numbers = [n1i * 10**n2i for n1i, n2i in zip(n1, n2)]
```

Sample output:

```
[800000, 7000, 200, 30000]
```

If you want repeats:

```
random.choices(numbers, k=6)
```

Sample output:

```
[800000, 7000, 800000, 800000, 7000, 200]
```

Comment: Definitely curious if this is what the OP wanted.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted to do but failed to find any example of it online but between your suggestion and @James suggestion, his suggestion seems simpler. Anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: @wwii I find it often the quickest to offer them something and then let them complain ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.random.randint(8, size=10)
array2 = np.random.randint(6, size=10)
array3 = (np.power(10, array2)) * array1
```

Arrays 'array1', 'array2' and 'array3'  are (examples):

```
array1 = [2 3 6 7 5 1 1 5 5 7]
array2 = [2 4 1 3 4 5 2 2 4 2]
array3 = [200 30000 60 7000 50000 100000 100 500 50000 700]
```

**array3** is what you want.